# How to remove the first line a cell in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to remove the first line in the content of a cell in Excel in bulk? For example, I have multiple lines in a cell and I want to remove them automatically. How can I do that? Let's say I want to remove the first line in cell H2 to H20. For example, each cell have more than 3 lines each.

I tried the MID function but I can't make it work.

Comment: `=TEXTAFTER(H2,Char(10))`?

Comment: or, for older versions: `=MID(H2,FIND(CHAR(10),H2)+1,LEN(H2))`?

Comment: `=MID(H2,FIND(CHAR(10),H2)+1,LEN(H2))` This one is what I actually tried but I am getting an error saying "There are one or more circular references where a formula refers to its own cell either directrly or indirectly."

Comment: That could be you are referencing in the same cell where you have applied the formula. Can you show a screencap?

Comment: Those formula must go into a different cell, they cannot refer to themselves.